# Can not send POST request to Paypal Connect from inside Laravel app

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, guzzle, paypal-connect

I have an app that connects to Paypal Connect. Upon Paypal connect button click I am taken to Paypal website and I do receive a code they send after authentication. But then I can't send the POST request to paypal with authorization_code to require user info I am receiving an error. I am getting this error:
Authentication failed due to invalid authentication credentials or a missing..
And I am pretty sure that my credentials are good.
Am I missing something?

This is what Paypal gives me:

```
curl -X POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \
-H 'Authorization: Basic {Your Base64-encoded ClientID:Secret}=' \
-d 'grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token={refresh token}'
```

I am using Guzzle to send post request. Please see code below

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$headers = [
    'Authorization' => 'Basic clientID:clientSecret'
];

$response = $client->request('POST',
'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token',
[
    'grant_type ' => 'authorization_code',
    'code' => $data['code']
], 
$headers);
```

Comment: You are adding the **clientID** and **clientSecret** to the header right?

Comment: Hi Jeemusu, thanks for answering. Yes sure I did. I just didn't put them in question

Comment: Are you using the latest version of guzzle? Looking at the docs it seems you may be using too many parameters. The request should look something like this `$client->request('POST', 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token', ['headers' => [], 'body' => []]);` . You could also try using the debug option to see if the final request is what you are expecting. http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#debug.

Comment: Hi Jeemusu. When I try and put grant_type and code inside body parameter, it tells me I should use form_params instead because it is deprecated. When I use form_params I got same error: Client error: `POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response: {"name":"AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE","message":"Authentication failed due to invalid authentication credentials or a missing ..
I am using Guzzle 6.3

Comment: Just to confirm, this is the code your using: `$client->request('POST', 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token', ['headers' => ['Authorization' => 'Basic {Your Base64-encoded ClientID:Secret}'], 'body' => ['grant_type ' => 'authorization_code','code' => $data['code']]]);` ?

You need to make sure your base65-encoding your ClientID:Secret. The final string will look something like `'Basic Y2xpZW50SUQ6Y2xpZW50U2VjcmV0'`

Comment: Yes, just instead of body I am using form_params because of deprecated error that pops up and I am getting this error:
Client error: `POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response: {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client Authentication failed"}

Comment: Ok, and your base 64 encoding the ClientID:Secret so it's a single string like 'Y2xpZW50SUQ6Y2xpZW50U2VjcmV0' ? You should be doing something like`base64_encode($ClientID . ':' . $Secret);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [paypal api documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/paypal-here/merchant-onboarding/permissions/#authentication-tokens), it appears as though your authorization header is incorrect.

> Authorization request header:
>   The Base64-encoded client ID and secret credentials separated by a
>   colon (:). Use the partner's credentials.

You can use php's [base64_encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) function to do this.

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

$authorizationString = base64_encode($clientId . ':' . $clientSecret);

$client->request(
    'POST', 
    'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token', 
    [
        'headers' => [
            'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . $authorizationString
        ], 
        'form_params' => [
            'grant_type ' => 'authorization_code',
            'code' => $data['code']
        ]
    ]
);
```

Comment: Hi Jeemusu, thanks for the answer. This solved my main problem but now I am getting another error: {"error":"unsupported_grant_type","error_description":"Grant Type is NULL"}

Comment: Sounds like the `form_params` aren't being sent. Maybe try switching back to using `body`?

Comment: Nah, it throws me the error of deprecation: 
Passing in the "body" request option as an array to send a POST request has been deprecated. Please use the "form_params" request option to send a application/x-www-form-urlencoded request, or the "multipart" request option to send a multipart/form-data request.

Comment: Try setting `'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',` in your headers array.

Comment: Yep, tried that one myself. Throws me the same error :(

Comment: I think you might need to change form_params to a string `'form_params' => 'grant_type= authorization_code&code=' .  $data['code']`

Comment: I would suggest using the debug flag to see what the final request looks like. You could also switch to using CURL (the paypal api linked in my answer shows the php curl code for making the same request) .You could also try testing the request using postman to see if you can get them working outside of your application, then compare the request string to what your getting from Guzzle.

Comment: Thanks Jeemusu. WIl try and find the solution. Thanks for patience

Comment: Fixed this one by adding double quotes in grant_type

Comment: Good to know! :)